# Using Checkbox as criteria in Query seacrh

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

trying to display a query list from another tab in the same document (ultimately more tabs) but would like it to only return results from the importrange that have a particular column with a ticked checkbox (col 15 in the below)

Currently

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(" G-Sheet URL ","' TAB range "),"Where Col15='TRUE'")
```

Think I'm missing a lot here - only currently results in the header row displaying no other data underneath...

Comment: Could you please share a copy of your spreadsheet, as well as the outcome you expect?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("G-Sheet URL", "TAB & range"), "where Col15=TRUE", 1)
```

Comment: thanks - it return only the first row from the data set for some reason?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you are looking for but try this formula as well.

> *only return results from the importrange that have a particular column with a ticked checkbox (col 15 in the below)*
>   *(assuming your check-box is in cell `Sheet1!O12`)*

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx","Sheet1!O3:O18"),"select Col1 Where '"&Sheet1!O12&"'='TRUE'",1)
```

If you have more than one columns in your import range you would call for:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","Sheet1!A3:T18"),"select Col15 Where '"&Sheet1!O12&"'='TRUE'",1)
```

Now if your check box could be anywhere in column 15 (`O`) you could try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","Sheet1!A3:T18"),"Where '"&VLOOKUP(TRUE,Sheet1!O1:O,1)&"'='TRUE'",1)
```

Comment: Did you try any of theses formulas?